# How to parametrize type in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have a type named AdapterInputDataType that defines a format of some kind of input data:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://companyname.org/AdapterInputDataTypeNS"
        xmlns:tns="http://companyname.org/AdapterInputDataTypeNS"
>

    <complexType name="AdapterInputDataType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="atomicElement" type="tns:AtomicElementType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="AtomicElementType">
        <simpleContent>
            <extension base="tns:AtomicElementValueType">
                <attribute name="elementName" type="tns:AtomicElementNameType" use="required"/>
            </extension>
        </simpleContent>
    </complexType>

    <simpleType name="AtomicElementValueType">
        <union memberTypes="string long decimal dateTime boolean"/>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="AtomicElementNameType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="foo"/>
            <enumeration value="bar"/>
            <enumeration value="baz"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>

</schema>
```

AdapterInputDataType is intended to define an element of this type inside of several namespaces:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://companyname.org/adapter1"
        xmlns:tns="http://companyname.org/adapter1"
        xmlns:inptypns="http://companyname.org/AdapterInputDataTypeNS"
>

    <import namespace="http://companyname.org/AdapterInputDataTypeNS"/>

    <element name="adapterInputData" type="inptypns:AdapterInputDataType"/>

</schema>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://companyname.org/adapter2"
        xmlns:tns="http://companyname.org/adapter2"
        xmlns:inptypns="http://companyname.org/AdapterInputDataTypeNS"
>

    <import namespace="http://companyname.org/AdapterInputDataTypeNS"/>

    <element name="adapterInputData" type="inptypns:AdapterInputDataType"/>

</schema>
```

The problem is that for each namespace the type is imported to a specific set of allowed values for elementName attribute should be defined. In other words, in different namespaces AdapterInputDataType should be based on different AtomicElementNameType types.

Is there a way to use in AdapterInputDataType definition some kind of parameter instead of AtomicElementNameType and put different AtomicElementNameType types in different namespaces as value of this parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution (thanks to Michael Kay for the hint about substitution groups).

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                targetNamespace="http://companyname.org/AdapterInputDataTypeNS"
                xmlns:tns="http://companyname.org/AdapterInputDataTypeNS"
>
        <import namespace="http://companyname.org/adapter1" schemaLocation="adapter1/ElementName.xsd"/>
        <import namespace="http://companyname.org/adapter2" schemaLocation="adapter2/ElementName.xsd"/>

        <element name="adapterInputData" type="tns:AdapterInputDataType" />

        <complexType name="AdapterInputDataType">
                <sequence>
                        <element name="atomicElement" type="tns:AtomicElementType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </sequence>
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="AtomicElementType">
                <sequence>
                        <element ref="tns:elementName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        <element name="elementValue" type="tns:AtomicElementValueType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </sequence>
        </complexType>

        <simpleType name="AtomicElementValueType">
                <union memberTypes="string long decimal dateTime boolean"/>
        </simpleType>

        <element name="elementName" type="string" abstract="true"/>

</schema>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                targetNamespace="http://companyname.org/adapter1"
                xmlns:tns="http://companyname.org/adapter1"
                xmlns:inptypns="http://companyname.org"
>

        <element name="elementName" type="tns:AtomicElementNameType" substitutionGroup="inptypns:elementName"/>

        <simpleType name="AtomicElementNameType">
                <restriction base="string">
                        <enumeration value="foo"/>
                        <enumeration value="bar"/>
                </restriction>
        </simpleType>

</schema>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                targetNamespace="http://companyname.org/adapter2"
                xmlns:tns="http://companyname.org/adapter2"
                xmlns:inptypns="http://companyname.org"
>

        <element name="elementName" type="tns:AtomicElementNameType" substitutionGroup="inptypns:elementName"/>

        <simpleType name="AtomicElementNameType">
                <restriction base="string">
                        <enumeration value="baz"/>
                </restriction>
        </simpleType>

</schema>
```

`AtomicElementType` is bit modified against one in original post. `elementName` attribute has been replaced with `elementName` child element. The cause is that an attribute can't be declared as abstract.
Here is an example of data valid against this schema:

```
<ans:adapterInputData xmlns:ans="http://companyname.org">
        <atomicElement>
                <ans1:elementName xmlns:ans1="http://companyname.org/adapter1">foo</ans1:elementName>
                <elementValue>hello</elementValue>
        </atomicElement>
        <atomicElement>
                <ans2:elementName xmlns:ans2="http://companyname.org/adapter2">baz</ans2:elementName>
                <elementValue>123</elementValue>
        </atomicElement>
</ans:adapterInputData>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like a case for substitution groups.

Define atomicAlement as a global element declaration with abstract="true", and then in various message-specific schema documents you can define concrete elements, using substitutionGroup="tns:atomicElement" to make them substitutable for the abstract element. The type of the concrete element must be the same as, or derived from, the type of the abstract element; this is often achieved by giving the abstract element type="xs:anyType".